# Trying to display a random joke, but the question and answers don't match from my local json file

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am trying to create a joke app, that displays a random joke from my local json file. Right now the question and the punchline that are displayed don't match. I tried using the id so that both question and answer appear, `<h1{this.getRandomJoke().answer}</h1>`, but the number assigned to that id appears. How can I make it work so that the question and punchline match?

This is how my local json file is set up:

```
const SportsJokesData = [
    {
        id: "1",
        question: "What did the baseball glove say to the ball?",
        answer: "Catch ya later!"

    }
]
export default SportsJokesData;
```

This is how I have my

```
import React from 'react'
import SportsJokesData from './SportsJokesData';

class SportsJokesApi extends React.Component {

    getRandomJoke(){
       return SportsJokesData[(SportsJokesData.length * Math.random()) << 0]

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
            <p>{this.getRandomJoke().question}</p>,
            <h1>{this.getRandomJoke().answer}</h1>
            </React.Fragment>           
        )
        }
    }
          export default SportsJokesApi;
```

Comment: Just so you know that file that you are calling JSON is not actually in JSON format. What you have is a modular Javascript file that uses array and object literal notation. It's similar to JSON but not the same, for example JSON needs `"`s around object property names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time you call `this.getRandomJoke()` you are getting a new item from that array. Do this:

```
import React from 'react'
import SportsJokesData from './SportsJokesData';

class SportsJokesApi extends React.Component {

    getRandomJoke(){
       return SportsJokesData[(SportsJokesData.length * Math.random()) << 0]

    }

    render() {
        const randomJoke =  this.getRandomJoke()

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
            <p>{randomJoke.question}</p>,
            <h1>{randomJoke.answer}</h1>
            </React.Fragment>           
        )
        }
    }
export default SportsJokesApi;
```